# Received invalid field length error in nodejs with mysql application

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm getting below error while fetching records (apx 50 rows) from my sql database. My application is developed in nodejs with express.
[image]

```
var common = require(__base + 'routes/common.js');
var dbhelper = require(__base + 'routes/dbhelper.js');

exports.GetStates = function (callback) {
    dbhelper.pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        // Use the connection
        connection.query('CALL GetStates()',
            function (err, res) {
                connection.release();
                if (err) {
                    common.ActionOutput.Status = common.ActionStatus.Error;
                    common.ActionOutput.Message = 'System Error: ' + err.message;
                } else {
                    common.ActionOutput.Status = common.ActionStatus.Success;
                    common.ActionOutput.Result = res[0][0];
                }
                return callback(JSON.stringify(common.ActionOutput));
            });
    });
};

dbhelper.js is

// Database connection
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: 'my ip',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'pass',,
    database: 'ssdsdas'
});
```

exports.pool = pool;

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error message but the causes of our issues might be different. Ultimately, the cause of my issue is that the column names in my stored procedure did not have back ticks (`) resulting in them being treated as variables.

Adding back ticks in my stored procedure body for column names fixed it.

Comment: Ok, in my case, when removed some columns from select statement, it worked for me.